# R Periodic Missing Plot Points

Tags: r, plot

I am having issues with R plots (probability density and scatter plots, see examples below) where R does not plot some data, in a regular periodic way.

This is a little hard to describe, so hopefully the pictures are helpful. Researching this question was somewhat difficult as any terms for "missing data" or "plot missing" even with terms "periodic" returns issues about imputation or visualization of missing data. If anyone has a better ideas for a question title, please suggest too. Below if some code that produces the problem on my system:

```
d2<-structure(list(height = c(151.765, 139.7, 136.525, 156.845, 145.415, 163.83, 
149.225, 168.91, 147.955, 165.1, 154.305, 151.13, 144.78, 149.9, 150.495, 
163.195, 157.48, 143.9418, 161.29, 156.21, 146.4, 148.59, 147.32, 147.955, 
161.925, 146.05, 146.05, 152.7048, 142.875, 142.875, 147.955, 160.655, 151.765, 
162.8648, 171.45, 147.32, 147.955, 154.305, 143.51, 146.7, 157.48, 165.735, 
152.4, 141.605, 158.8, 155.575, 164.465, 151.765, 161.29, 154.305, 145.415, 
145.415, 152.4, 163.83, 144.145, 153.67, 142.875, 167.005, 158.4198, 165.735, 
149.86, 154.94, 160.9598, 161.925, 147.955, 159.385, 148.59, 136.525, 158.115, 
144.78, 156.845, 179.07, 170.18, 146.05, 147.32, 162.56, 152.4, 160.02, 149.86, 
142.875, 167.005, 159.385, 154.94, 162.56, 152.4, 170.18, 146.05, 159.385, 
151.13, 160.655, 169.545, 158.75, 149.86, 153.035, 161.925, 162.56, 149.225, 
163.195, 161.925, 145.415, 163.195, 151.13, 150.495, 170.815, 157.48, 152.4, 
147.32, 145.415, 157.48, 154.305, 167.005, 142.875, 152.4, 160, 159.385, 149.86, 
160.655, 160.655, 149.225, 140.97, 154.94, 141.605, 160.02, 150.1648, 155.575, 
156.21, 153.035, 167.005, 149.86, 147.955, 159.385, 161.925, 155.575, 159.385, 
146.685, 172.72, 166.37, 141.605, 151.765, 156.845, 148.59, 157.48, 149.86, 
147.955, 153.035, 160.655, 149.225, 138.43, 162.56, 149.225, 158.75, 149.86, 
158.115, 156.21, 148.59, 143.51, 154.305, 157.48, 157.48, 154.305, 168.275, 
145.415, 149.225, 154.94, 162.56, 156.845, 161.0106, 144.78, 143.51, 149.225, 
149.86, 165.735, 144.145, 157.48, 154.305, 163.83, 156.21, 144.145, 162.56, 
146.05, 154.94, 144.78, 146.685, 152.4, 163.83, 165.735, 156.21, 152.4, 140.335, 
163.195, 151.13, 171.1198, 149.86, 163.83, 141.605, 149.225, 146.05, 161.29, 
162.56, 145.415, 170.815, 159.385, 159.4, 153.67, 160.02, 150.495, 149.225, 
142.875, 142.113, 147.32, 162.56, 164.465, 160.02, 153.67, 167.005, 151.13, 
153.035, 139.065, 152.4, 154.94, 147.955, 144.145, 155.575, 150.495, 155.575, 
154.305, 157.48, 168.91, 150.495, 160.02, 167.64, 144.145, 145.415, 160.02, 
164.465, 153.035, 149.225, 160.02, 149.225, 153.67, 150.495, 151.765, 158.115, 
149.225, 151.765, 154.94, 161.29, 148.59, 160.655, 157.48, 167.005, 157.48, 
152.4, 152.4, 161.925, 152.4, 159.385, 142.24, 168.91, 160.02, 158.115, 152.4, 
155.575, 154.305, 156.845, 156.21, 168.275, 147.955, 157.48, 160.7, 161.29, 
150.495, 163.195, 148.59, 148.59, 161.925, 153.67, 151.13, 163.83, 153.035, 
151.765, 156.21, 140.335, 158.75, 142.875, 151.9428, 161.29, 160.9852, 144.78, 
160.02, 160.9852, 165.989, 157.988, 154.94, 160.655, 147.32, 146.7, 147.32, 
172.9994, 158.115, 147.32, 165.989, 149.86, 161.925, 163.83, 160.02, 154.94, 
152.4, 146.05, 151.9936, 151.765, 144.78, 160.655, 151.13, 153.67, 147.32, 
139.7, 157.48, 154.94, 143.51, 158.115, 147.32, 160.02, 165.1, 154.94, 153.67, 
141.605, 163.83, 161.29, 154.9, 161.3, 170.18, 149.86, 160.655, 154.94, 166.37, 
148.2852, 151.765, 148.59, 153.67, 146.685, 154.94, 156.21, 160.655, 146.05, 
156.21, 152.4, 162.56, 142.875, 162.56, 156.21, 158.75), weight = c(47.8256065, 
36.4858065, 31.864838, 53.0419145, 41.276872, 62.992589, 38.2434755, 55.4799715, 
34.869885, 54.487739, 49.89512, 41.220173, 36.0322145, 47.7, 33.849303, 
48.5626935, 42.3258035, 38.3568735, 48.987936, 42.7226965, 35.493574, 
37.9032815, 35.4652245, 40.312989, 55.111428, 37.5063885, 38.498621, 46.606578, 
38.838815, 35.5786225, 47.400364, 47.8823055, 49.4131785, 49.384829, 56.5572525, 
39.12231, 49.89512, 41.2485225, 38.55532, 42.4, 44.6504625, 58.5984165, 
46.719976, 44.22522, 50.9, 54.317642, 45.8978405, 48.024053, 52.219779, 
47.62716, 45.642695, 42.410852, 36.4858065, 55.9335635, 37.194544, 48.307548, 
37.3362915, 47.173568, 47.286966, 57.549485, 37.931631, 47.2019175, 43.204638, 
50.2636635, 39.3774555, 50.689, 39.4341545, 36.28736, 46.266384, 42.2691045, 
47.62716, 55.7067675, 48.5626935, 42.807745, 35.0683315, 56.755699, 51.255896, 
47.230267, 40.936678, 32.715323, 57.0675435, 42.977842, 39.9444455, 45.9545395, 
41.106775, 47.5988105, 37.5063885, 45.019006, 42.2691045, 54.8562825, 53.523856, 
52.1914295, 42.410852, 49.5832755, 41.730464, 56.018612, 42.1557065, 53.0986135, 
50.235314, 42.52425, 49.101334, 38.498621, 49.8100715, 59.760746, 47.9390045, 
39.292407, 36.8826995, 42.127357, 44.565414, 47.853956, 55.1964765, 32.998818, 
40.879979, 51.2, 49.044635, 53.4388075, 54.090846, 55.3665735, 42.240755, 
40.936678, 49.6966735, 44.338618, 45.9545395, 41.95726, 51.482692, 44.111822, 
32.205032, 56.755699, 52.673371, 36.4858065, 48.8461885, 56.9541455, 42.0990075, 
50.178615, 46.549879, 61.80191, 48.987936, 31.524644, 35.2951275, 45.642695, 
43.885026, 45.5576465, 39.008912, 41.163474, 45.245802, 53.637254, 52.3048275, 
39.0939605, 45.699394, 40.3980375, 51.482692, 38.668718, 39.235708, 44.338618, 
39.519203, 31.071052, 46.776675, 40.6248335, 50.178615, 41.276872, 54.6, 
44.9906565, 35.8054185, 45.2174525, 48.1091015, 45.6710445, 48.420946, 
41.1918235, 38.4135725, 42.127357, 38.2434755, 48.3358975, 38.9238635, 
40.029494, 50.2069645, 54.2892925, 45.6, 39.4341545, 43.204638, 31.864838, 
45.4442485, 38.045029, 36.0889135, 40.879979, 47.910655, 47.7122085, 46.379782, 
41.163474, 36.5992045, 48.137451, 36.7126025, 56.5572525, 38.6970675, 
47.4854125, 36.2023115, 41.276872, 44.7638605, 50.4337605, 55.281525, 37.931631, 
58.456669, 44.4236665, 44.4, 44.565414, 44.622113, 40.483086, 44.0834725, 
34.416293, 32.772022, 35.947166, 49.5549, 53.183662, 37.081146, 40.5114355, 
50.6038575, 43.9700745, 49.89, 33.5941575, 43.8566765, 48.137451, 42.751046, 
33.906002, 39.7176495, 35.947166, 50.915702, 45.756093, 49.214732, 58.8252125, 
43.4597835, 51.9646335, 50.688906, 34.246196, 39.3774555, 59.5622995, 52.16308, 
39.972795, 43.941725, 54.601137, 45.075705, 41.333571, 41.900561, 42.524, 
43.147939, 40.82328, 42.864444, 46.209685, 47.853956, 42.52425, 48.5059945, 
45.869491, 52.900167, 47.570461, 43.544832, 43.431434, 53.2120115, 44.678812, 
47.2019175, 31.6663915, 56.4438545, 55.791816, 47.4854125, 45.1607535, 
45.529297, 48.874538, 46.5782285, 43.885026, 56.0469615, 40.086193, 50.802304, 
46.3, 49.3564795, 44.111822, 51.0291, 40.766581, 37.5630875, 51.59609, 
44.8205595, 43.4030845, 46.719976, 39.5475525, 34.7848365, 39.292407, 
37.4496895, 48.6760915, 35.606972, 43.714929, 48.19415, 50.972401, 43.998424, 
48.19415, 46.6916265, 56.415505, 48.591043, 48.2224995, 47.4854125, 35.550273, 
36.6, 48.9595865, 51.255896, 46.5215295, 36.967748, 48.647742, 38.045029, 
47.286966, 55.394923, 54.204244, 48.477645, 43.0628905, 34.189497, 49.951819, 
44.338618, 33.45241, 47.286966, 46.1246365, 47.400364, 40.8516295, 50.348712, 
45.132404, 42.240755, 41.6454155, 45.2174525, 51.255896, 49.271431, 51.199197, 
43.8566765, 35.5219235, 42.88542, 46.776675, 41.8722115, 38.2, 43.3, 53.637254, 
42.977842, 39.7743485, 43.3463855, 52.673371, 38.441922, 42.807745, 35.890467, 
44.22522, 38.0733785, 44.111822, 44.0267735, 47.8823055, 39.405805, 41.050076, 
40.82328, 47.0318205, 34.246196, 52.16308, 54.0624965, 52.5316235), age = c(63, 
63, 65, 41, 51, 35, 32, 27, 19, 54, 47, 66, 73, 20, 65.3, 36, 44, 31, 39, 29, 
56, 45, 19, 29, 30, 24, 35, 33, 27, 32, 36, 24, 30, 24, 52, 42, 19, 55, 43, 20, 
18, 42, 44, 60, 20, 37, 50, 50, 31, 25, 23, 52, 79.3, 35, 27, 38, 39, 30, 24, 
51, 46, 22, 29, 38, 30, 45, 47, 79, 45, 54, 31, 23, 41, 23, 36, 30, 34, 44, 43, 
73.3, 38, 43, 33, 35, 29, 58, 53, 51, 48, 29, 41, 81.75, 35, 46, 29, 42, 27, 22, 
43, 53, 43, 41, 50, 33, 62, 49, 22, 29, 33, 34, 42, 40, 27, 25, 29, 45, 26, 45, 
45, 85.5999999999999, 26, 24, 57, 22, 24, 21, 79, 50, 40, 64, 32, 38.7, 26, 63, 
62, 22, 41, 19, 74, 41, 33, 53, 18, 37, 61, 44, 35, 23, 55, 53, 59, 57, 35, 29, 
62, 18, 51, 19, 42, 25, 41, 37, 82, 28, 50, 43, 31, 67, 39, 18, 48, 30, 64, 72, 
68, 44, 43, 34, 62, 44, 31, 29, 62, 67, 57, 32, 24, 77, 62, 67, 70, 37, 58, 35, 
30, 26, 21, 41, 46, 49, 28, 83, 54, 54, 68, 68, 56, 57, 22, 40, 19, 41, 
75.9000000000001, 73.9000000000001, 49, 26, 88, 68, 33, 26, 56, 34, 74, 69, 50, 
44, 18, 41, 27, 38, 57, 64.5, 42, 24, 71, 49.5, 33, 28, 47, 27, 55, 
83.4000000000001, 63, 52, 49, 31, 35, 35, 24, 41, 32, 43, 63, 21, 55, 38, 28, 
36, 38, 48, 45, 38, 21, 50, 41, 30, 21, 38, 19, 31, 21, 50, 39, 44, 36, 36, 18, 
58, 58, 33, 21.5, 26, 22, 28, 42, 21, 19, 48, 46, 25, 51, 25, 28, 26, 54, 66, 
20, 25, 38, 51, 48, 27, 22, 60, 43, 27, 30, 29, 23, 30, 41, 42, 43, 35, 75.5, 
64, 38, 24.2, 26, 19, 43, 38, 23, 49, 41, 23, 43, 21, 24, 20, 20, 34, 29, 65, 
46, 43, 39, 43, 70, 26, 48, 44, 33, 41, 37.4, 53, 49, 27, 31, 31, 21, 68), male 
= c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("height", 
"weight", "age", "male"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 
77L, 79L, 80L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 100L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 112L, 113L, 117L, 118L, 
119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 
136L, 137L, 138L, 140L, 142L, 143L, 146L, 147L, 150L, 151L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 173L, 
174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 190L, 
191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 202L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 218L, 219L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
226L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 242L, 
244L, 245L, 247L, 248L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 258L, 259L, 
260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 265L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 272L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 
277L, 278L, 279L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 293L, 
294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 300L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 313L, 
314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 330L, 336L, 337L, 340L, 
341L, 342L, 343L, 346L, 347L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 357L, 358L, 366L, 367L, 
372L, 374L, 375L, 380L, 383L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 393L, 397L, 398L, 400L, 
403L, 406L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 422L, 
423L, 424L, 425L, 427L, 428L, 430L, 431L, 434L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 442L, 
443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 451L, 452L, 454L, 458L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 
464L, 465L, 469L, 470L, 473L, 474L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 482L, 483L, 485L, 
486L, 489L, 491L, 492L, 494L, 496L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 506L, 
507L, 510L, 511L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 519L, 524L, 525L, 529L, 530L, 533L, 534L, 
535L, 538L, 541L, 542L, 544L), class = "data.frame")

mu.list <- seq( from=140, to=160 , length.out=200 )
sigma.list <- seq( from=4 , to=9 , length.out=200 )
post <- expand.grid( mu=mu.list , sigma=sigma.list )
mu.list <- seq( from=140, to=160 , length.out=200 )
sigma.list <- seq( from=4 , to=9 , length.out=200 )
post <- expand.grid( mu=mu.list , sigma=sigma.list )
post$LL <- sapply( 1:nrow(post) , function(i) sum( dnorm(
  d2$height ,
  mean=post$mu[i] ,
  sd=post$sigma[i] ,
  log=TRUE ) ) )
post$prod <- post$LL + dnorm( post$mu , 178 , 20 , TRUE ) +
  dunif( post$sigma , 0 , 50 , TRUE )
post$prob <- exp( post$prod - max(post$prod) )
sample.rows <- sample( 1:nrow(post) , size=1e4 , replace=TRUE , prob=post$prob )
sample.mu <- post$mu[ sample.rows ]
sample.sigma <- post$sigma[ sample.rows ]
```

But when I plot this, R is not plotting certain points at periodic intervals:

```
plot(sample.mu)
```

[image: X]

But no problem plotting the other vector
    plot(sample.sigma)

[image: X]

I have reproduced this using Rcmdr, so does not appear to be specific to Rstudio (my normal IDE). What is it about the `vector sample.mu` that is causing this problem? Also, if anyone has a better idea as to what to title this question, please suggest. Thanks in advance for your help.

The output of sessionInfo() for me is:

> R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Linux Mint 18.3
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
>   LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN1qg.png) LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUHOL.png)
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
>   LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  [7] methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] rethinking_1.59    rstan_2.17.3
>   StanHeaders_2.17.2 [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5FKN.png) ggplot2_3.0.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.18
>   rstudioapi_0.6     magrittr_1.5        [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5FKN.png) bindr_0.1.1
>   MASS_7.3-50        munsell_0.5.0       [7] colorspace_1.3-2
>   lattice_0.20-35    R6_2.2.0           [10] rlang_0.2.2
>   plyr_1.8.4         dplyr_0.7.4        [13] tools_3.4.4
>   grid_3.4.4         gtable_0.2.0       [16] loo_2.0.0
>   coda_0.19-1        withr_2.1.2        [19] matrixStats_0.54.0
>   yaml_2.2.0         lazyeval_0.2.1     [22] assertthat_0.2.0
>   tibble_1.4.2       crayon_1.3.4       [25] bindrcpp_0.2.2
>   gridExtra_2.3      inline_0.3.15      [28] glue_1.3.0
>   compiler_3.4.4     pillar_1.3.0       [31] scales_1.0.0
>   stats4_3.4.4       mvtnorm_1.0-8      [34] pkgconfig_2.0.2

Comment: Your object `d2` cannot be found so it is impossible to reproduce your results. Could you provide that?

Comment: Thank you for catching @ekstroem the missing variables. I have fixed the code now, thank you again.

Comment: Looks like data where the bandwidth is too narrow for the precision of measurements. Like maybe all the `sample.mu` data is rounded to the nearest `0.1` (or some such rounding)? My advice would be use a bigger bandwidth

Comment: Thanks @Gregor but unfortunately `dens(sample.mu, adjust=0.1)` and `plot(sample.mu, adjust=0.1)` do not seem to correct the problem.

Comment: @ekstroem and @Gregor I realize the rethinking package is not standard in the repositories so I've adjusted my example code to not require `library(rethinking)` thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of reasons for the plots you see and they all have to do with the way you generate and sample your data.

First, both `mu.list` and `sigma.list` consist of random samples of your two lists and the both have length 200. You are sampling rows from this expanded list (via `expand.grid()`) but because of the probabilities of the individual rows and the order of the lists produced by `expand.grid()` you extract different number of unique values for each of the lists.

```
> length(unique(sample.mu))
[1] 32
> length(unique(sample.sigma))
[1] 82
```

You can see why if you plot the `post$mu` and `post$sigma` against the probabilities of being selected:

```
> plot(post$prod, post$mu)
> plot(post$prod, post$sigma)
```

This produces this graph

[image]

As you can see the curvature along the right-hand side (more likely to be sampled) is stronger for `post$mu` than for `post$sigma`. Consequently, you get more unique values for sigma than you do for mu. The lower number of unique values for mu can be seen in your plot because of the original grid from `mu.list`. Because of the larger number of unique values for sigma, you see overplotting of the circles so the grid "disappears".

In other words: no points are missing and the plots are as expected.

Comment: thank you for spending the time to put your answer together. I really appreciate it. It seems pretty straightforward now. Do you think re-titling this question (to "Recognizing Overplotting" or something like that) would make it more useful or easier to find for other people?

Comment: @Flaunk I don't think adding "overplotting" to the title will help as it is not overplotting that is the problem. Rather overplotting masks the grid content of your data.

Comment: Oh - and if the answer answers your question then please accept it.